# How can I give a custom ButtonStyle in SwiftUI additional options

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I currently have a ButtonStyle defined as below:

```swift
struct RoundedButtonRed: ButtonStyle {
  func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    HStack {
      Spacer()
      configuration.label.foregroundColor(.white)
      Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
    .background(Color.red.cornerRadius(13.0))
    .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.85 : 1)
  }
}
```

I also have another struct (`RoundedButtonBlack`) that has a `.background(Color.black.cornerRadius(13.0))`, which seems like unnecessary code duplication. Is there a way to add custom configuration options so that I can use the same struct for different colors?

e.g.

```swift
struct RoundedButtonRed: ButtonStyle {
  func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    HStack {
      Spacer()
      configuration.label.foregroundColor(.white)
      Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
    .background(configuration.backgroundColor) // background color taken from configuration or passed into .buttonStyle(RoundedButton()) call
    .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.85 : 1)
  }
}
```

Or, perhaps there is a better way altogether?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add a property inside your `RoundedButton` struct that stores a color. Then, when you apply it with `buttonStyle`, you can pass in any color you want.

```
struct RoundedButton: ButtonStyle {
    var color: Color /// add property here
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            configuration.label.foregroundColor(.white)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()  /// use it here
        .background(color.cornerRadius(13.0))
        .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.85 : 1)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {                                                     /// pass it in here
            Button("Red button") {}.buttonStyle(RoundedButton(color: .red))
            Button("Black button") {}.buttonStyle(RoundedButton(color: .black))
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Red button on top of black button]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [the @aheze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68106298/5623035), you can make it appear like a native modifier by defining a simple extension ([Suggested by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/creating-a-card-view#Customize-the-label-style)) like:

```
extension ButtonStyle where Self == RoundedButton {
    static func rounded(_ color: Color) -> Self {
        Self(color: color)
    }
}
```

So now you can use it like:

```
Button("Red button") { }
    .buttonStyle(.rounded(.red)) //  Much more cleaner call
```